# Update statement in SQL Server using two tables

Tags: sql-server

This my query

```
UPDATE #Student_tbl
SET MStudentId = (SELECT StudentId
                  FROM #StudentHistory_tbl
                  WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId
                                       FROM #Student_tbl)
                 )
```

it returns an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do here?

Comment: Indeed, what *are* you trying to do here? Update non-existent rows from historical data? Because that's what the subquery says `Where User ID not IN`. Are you trying to do an INSERT perhaps? Or something else?

Comment: The query doesn't explain anything - it doesn't make sense. Explain what you want to do, not how you think it should be done. You *can* use joins in INSERT and UPDATE queries, so you *can* insert missing rows, or update existing ones

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly explicit, when you write:

```
UPDATE #Student_tbl 
SET MStudentId = (
Select StudentId 
from #StudentHistory_tbl 
where UserId not in (select UserId from #Student_tbl)
)
```

You are updating all rows in the #Student_tbl. You are trying to set MSStudentId to equal multiple rows, as your select does not return just one row.

You would have to look at either your subquery, to get it to return 1 row, or join the subquery to the 'StudnetHistory_tbl so you are updating the column with a singular row value.

Comment: how can i check the condition

Comment: Without knowing the data structure, I couldn't really say, but if there is a foreign key between the tables, you would join on that. Post up some sample data from the #Student_tbl and the #StudentHistory_tbl if you need some help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOINS in update statements. Try something like this:

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     t1.MStudentId = t2.Studentid
FROM    #Student_tbl AS t1
        INNER JOIN #StudentHistory_tbl AS t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId
WHERE   t1.MStudentId <> t2.Studentid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
UPDATE #Student_tbl 
SET MStudentId= a.StudentId
from (Select StudentId,UserId from #StudentHistory_tbl ,#Student_tbl
where #StudentHistory_tbl.UserId <> #Student_tbl.UserId ) a
where a.UserId <> #Student_tbl.UserId
```

OR

```
UPDATE #Student_tbl 
SET MStudentId= a.StudentId
from (Select StudentId,UserId from #StudentHistory_tbl
where UserId not in (select UserId from #Student_tbl) ) a
where a.UserId not in (select UserId from #Student_tbl)
```

Comment: Here a belongs to which table

Comment: a is for inner query selecting UserId of #StudentHistory which are not present in #Student_tbl. Is it working or not?

Comment: it showing error at a.UserId. there is a incorrect syntax near a.UserId

Comment: Here i want to return records which are not in #Student_tbl ,but those are in #StudentHistory_tbl.Your query is not working.

Comment: then in outer where try this a.UserId < > #Student_tbl.UserId

Comment: the table #Student_tbl contains 77 records actually it should has 104 records

Comment: Here the remaining records i want to update into #Student_tbl from #StudentHistory_tbl

Comment: try this UPDATE #Student_tbl 
SET MStudentId= a.StudentId
from (Select StudentId,UserId from #StudentHistory_tbl
where UserId not in (select UserId from #Student_tbl) ) a
where a.UserId not in (select UserId from #Student_tbl)